# Ubuntu CD Install

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to install new version from CD over Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot.
I get this error message every time:

```
The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again.
```

Answer (score -1):

you can find a solution here : [CLICK ME](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460847&highlight=unrecoverable%20error%2010.04)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: sorry about that. i thought it is ok to just put the link. next time i will be more careful.